# Using set_http_authentication_callback(self, callback)

Tags: python, http-authentication, spynner

I'm using a spynner package fo Python and when I try to load a page like this:

sb = spynner.Browser()

sb.load(URL)

I have an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spynner-1.10-py2.7.egg\spynner\browser.py", line 207, in _on_authentication_required
    if not self._http_authentication_callback:
AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute '_http_authentication_callback'
QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting

I think that I should use a function:
set_http_authentication_callback(self, callback)
before I use a load function.
But I don't know how.
Can anybody show me an example how to use this function??

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, declare a function named, for example http_auth_callback in the scope in which you are working(ex. in your class or globally)

```
def http_auth_callback(arguments):
    print dir(arguments)
```

Try something like this:

```
sb = spynner.Browser()

sb.set_http_authentication_callback(http_auth_callback) # if using global scope
sb.set_http_authentication_callback(self.http_auth_callback) # if inside a class and the callback function is declared as a method

sb.load(URL)
```

Comment: ok thank you for response, I make it like in your example, and when the page is loaded, after few second i saw this: QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting  ,Have you any idea what is the reason??

Comment: Ok, It works, of course in Http_auth_callback should be:             return ('username','password') then authentication is correct.